# Cannot create Order History CSV download for customers in Prestashop

Tags: csv, download, prestashop

Have been stuck with this issue since the last 4 days and checked everywhere but I cannot find a solution.

In Prestashop, I need to offer customers (for a b2b site) csv downloads for each of their order histories. This is what I have done:

1- Overridden *OrderDetailController.php* and written the following code under *initContent()*:

```
if ( !array_key_exists('csv_download', $_GET) ) {
    parent::initContent();
} else if ( array_key_exists('csv_download', $_GET) ) {
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.'abc'.'_'.date('Y-m-d_His').'.csv"');
    $this->context->smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'order-detail-csv.tpl');
}
```

The order-detail-csv.tpl is:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

(I've have hardcoded values in the template for testing purposes)

The problem is, when the link is clicked to access this, the following is appended at the bottom of the CSV:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
<!-- MODULE Block footer -->
<div class="block_various_links" id="block_various_links_footer">
<p class="title_block">Information</p>
<ul>
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: PS_CATALOG_MODE in <b>D:\Program_Files\xampp\htdocs  \prestashop\cache\smarty\compile\66\40\fc\6640fcf250c9a844925d45d85c39618c4233b46e.file.blockcms.tpl.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Trying to get property of non-object in <b>D:\Program_Files\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\cache\smarty\compile\66\40\fc\6640fcf250c9a844925d45d85c39618c4233b46e.file.blockcms.tpl.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br />
<li class="first_item"><a href="<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: link in <b>D:\Program_Files\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\cache\smarty\compile\66\40\fc\6640fcf250c9a844925d45d85c39618c4233b46e.file.blockcms.tpl.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Trying to get property of non-object in <b>D:\Program_Files\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\cache\smarty\compile\66\40\fc\6640fcf250c9a844925d45d85c39618c4233b46e.file.blockcms.tpl.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>: Call to a member function getPageLink() on a non-object in <b>D:\Program_Files\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\cache\smarty\compile\66\40\fc\6640fcf250c9a844925d45d85c39618c4233b46e.file.blockcms.tpl.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br />
```

Checked further and the problem is that the message printing at the bottom of the CSV is from a module hook called 'CMS block'.
If I go into admin-> modules->positions-> select CMS block, I can remove this hook from the footer area by typing 'orderdetail' in the exceptions field.

But then the error message is replaced by another error message for another hook and if I remove that aswell, it goes on and on. It is not practical edit every module position and add orderdetail as an exception.

There must be a proper way of doing this so that prestashop can ignore the smarty layout and all positional module hooks and send out pure csv (represented by *order-detail-csv.tpl* above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found a solution. Not the prestashop way ideally but does the job.

Rather than using using the prestashop MVC to serve CSV order histories to customers (was a nightmare!), I have created a standalone php script and placed it under the prestashop root directory and I access it directly with the required GET params:

(I'm still using the Prestashop config to connect to db and use the context class to access the user's cookie data)

```
<?php
 require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');

$context = Context::getContext();

header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download; charset=UTF-8');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.'abc'.'_'.date('Y-m-d_His').'.csv"');

try {
    $csv_string="";

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='._DB_SERVER_.';dbname='._DB_NAME_, _DB_USER_, _DB_PASSWD_);

    $query = " SELECT
            o.*,
            od.*
        FROM
            orders o
        INNER JOIN
            order_detail od ON od.id_order = o.id_order
        WHERE
            o.id_customer = ".$context->customer->id;

    if(isset($_GET['id_order']) && !empty($_GET['id_order'])) {
        $query = $query." AND o.id_order = ".$_GET['id_order'];
    } else if(isset($_GET['from']) && !empty($_GET['from'])) {
        $query = $query." AND o.date_add > '".$_GET['from']."' AND o.date_add < '".$_GET['to']."'";
    }

    //Get column names
    $fetch_type = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC;
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $col_row = $result->fetchAll($fetch_type);
    $columns = empty($col_row) ? array() : array_keys((array)$col_row[0]);
    //assemble csv
    foreach($columns as $col) {
        $csv_string = $csv_string.$col.', ';
    }

    //get values
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    //assemble csv
    foreach($result as $row) {
         $csv_string = $csv_string."\n";
         foreach($columns as $col) {
             $csv_string = $csv_string . $row[$col].', ';
         }
    }

    echo($csv_string);

    $conn = null;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

Obviously the above script needs conditional checks to stop it from crapping out if accessed by someone who isn't logged in or with the wrong GET params (Which I will do later. Out of this topic).

It at least does the task I needed it to do .